# trying to fill out a table using sumproduct based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have two different Excel sheets that I am trying to take the numbers from one page and fill out a table on another page based on some conditions. Here is an example :

I need to take zbl-1 and zbl-2 from page YY and fill out the "Met" column on page ZZ. Here is what I have written in my excel sheet but I get a #VALUE error. Any suggestions please?
on page ZZ:

```
name    Sample              Met                    Norm Area
aba     CDS23D073         #VALUE                   6.68E-02
baa     CDS23D074         #VALUE                   6.11E-02
cab     CDS23D075         #VALUE                   4.48E-02
cba     zbl-1             #VALUE                   5.15E-02
cca     zbl-2             #VALUE                   5.16E-02
```

On page YY:

```
mA    zbl-1   zbl-2
aba   0.24    2.24
baa   2.79    36.47
cab   9.68    62.11
cba   4.48    21.18
cca   2.22    10.61
```

Comment: So what formula did you use, what do you expect as a result?

Comment: _Re:_ _"Here is what I have written in my excel sheet but I get a #VALUE error"_ but there is no formula shown. Also, based on your data, there will be two cells which will have an expected output because samples `CDS23D073`, `CDS23D074` & `CDS23D075` no data shown for them in `YY`

Comment: yeah, sorry I forgot to paste the formula that I am using : =SUMPRODUCT(--(ZZ!$A2:$A7=YY!$A$2), --(ZZ!$B2:$B7=YY!$B$1),YY!$B2:$B7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in column Met first cell and copy paste down. Supposed that tables are placed from A1 on both sheet.

```
=INDEX(YY!A$1:C$6;MATCH(A2;YY!A$1:A$6;0);MATCH(B2;YY!A$1:C$1;0))
```

Result

[image]